# Is there a Sonar API to get line level coverage for a given resource?

Tags: sonarqube, clover

I am running clover before running the sonar ant task and providing its xml output to Sonar 3.7. 
Is it possible to later fetch the line level coverage data for a given Java file using one of the Sonar webservice API's?

If not, is there a library that I can use to get  the same info from clover xml without writing all the parsing code?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you need a complete report to line level granularity.
You should go for html reports of Clover.

They provide details from the highest level such as project and packages to lowest level of details like complexity of each package or source file, method coverage, line coverage etc.  (If proper attributes are specified)

Many of the above specified things are provided in XML report as well but HTML generated by Clover is very interactive and fancy. You can actually see all the source files in that report and figure out the parts which were covered in the file.

As you already have the xml report generation target, you can add html report task as well into it.

Hope this helps. :)